# SPFx PNP people picker error for allowUnvalidated

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker, pnp

I am using PNP SPFx React PeoplePicker in my SPFx webpart. But when I add `allowUnvalidated` property to my PeoplePicker. I get this error:

> Property 'allowUnvalidated' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)

I also change the SPFx version from 1.11 to 1.14 but still get the same error.

Below is the code that I have used:

```
import {
  PeoplePicker,
  PrincipalType,
  IPeoplePickerUserItem,
} from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/PeoplePicker";

     <PeoplePicker
            context={porps.context as any}
            personSelectionLimit={3}
            groupName={""}
            onChange={_addUser}
            principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User, PrincipalType.SecurityGroup]}
            resolveDelay={200}
            defaultSelectedUsers={_Picker}
            allowUnvalidated={true}
          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [release history of PnP SPFx Controls library](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/releases),

`allowUnvalidated` property in PeoplePicker control is added in `v3.9.0` release.

So, try using latest version of PnP SPFx Controls library.

**For example**:

You can install specific version of library using command like below:

```
npm install @pnp/spfx-controls-react@3.11.0 --save --save-exact
```

Comment: Please **[Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)** and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.